# How to execute a makefile from R

Tags: r, makefile

I am new to using makefiles in **R**, so excuse the really simple question: How do I execute a makefile which resides in a folder using R?

Is there a way to do so using a .R script? If so, what would the command line include?

Comment: I don't know R but if the question is how to run `make` then, absent any specific directions, you just run `make` in the directory with the `Makefile`.

Comment: @EtanReisner it is exactly this last point that I do not know - run the make? I am completely new to it and struggling with the basics it seems.. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's it. You run `make`. That's the entire command line in normal cases. Just run `make` from the correct directory. The same way you would run anything else from R (this is the bit I can't help with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem in calling **make** using R (assuming you use **Windows** and **RStudio**):

Turns out you first need to add [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to your PATH

- Select Avanced System Settings / Environment Variables / System Variables New.
- Add the following to PATH:

  - C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
  - C:\Rtools\bin
  - Now Reboot.
- After this is done, reopen your R console. Now you can use @yihui's [servr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/servr/index.html) package, and call a folder containing a **makefile** as follows:

  ```
  servr::make(dir="path containing Makefile")
  ```

Hope this helps other newbies to makefile too...